# Equal height columns in Firefox (CSS)

Tags: html, css, firefox, dynamic-columns

I have an issue with equal height columns and I know these sort of questions are asked technically all the time (from what I got from my research) but unfortunately I've hit a point at which I just don't know what else to try.

I have my equal height columns in Chrome and Opera but somehow Firefox doesn't like the way I did it.

I have a simple mark up

```
<section id="env">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Way more content than in all the others because this one has so much to say and doesn't know when to stop...it always does that...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and the #env div is displayed as a table, the .container divs as table-cells.

```
#env {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  border 25px solid transparent;
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

I created a fiddle for this to focus on the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vy3Lzu75/1/

If you open it in Chrome or Opera, you should see three equally high, red columns. In Firefox, however, the red columns correspond to their individual content instead of to the actual container.

I'd be very greatful if anyone can point me into the right direction because everything I've tried so far (setting height of parent to 1px, setting min-height of child, different display values...) didn't do the trick in FF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your columns are already equal heights, it is the `.container` wich draws the column/cell. `.content` is just the content ;) https://jsfiddle.net/vy3Lzu75/2/

Comment: Oh god...this is actually pretty stupid :D You know, I actually needed the layout like that (so I thought) to have my columns keep a certain distance to eachother (the width of the transparent border). But I can just increase the border-spacing of the #env div, can't I? Has basically the same effect from what I see it. Geez...
Anyway, thanks so much for the hint. Now I can get it to work.

But still, would you happen to know the reason for the different behaviour regarding the content in this case in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: And what do I do now to mark this question as basically solved (since I can't mark a comment as solution, I think)?

Comment: For some reason webkit engines accepts 100% height from a table-cell size where there is not real reference in the style sheet to calculate those 100% , i believe Firefox behaves fine here .

Comment: I'll add an answser and give a hint with flex too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cells are here drawing the columns. border-spacing can be used to set some area around .

```css
#env {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px 5px;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33333%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
}

p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="env">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Way more content than in all the others because this one has so much to say and doesn't know when to stop...it always does that...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy3Lzu75/2/

---

If you want the content to fill all space avalaible, you need to inbricate flex boxes and margin comes avalaible to separate each cols :

```css
#env {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  margin:5px 30px;
  width: 33.33333%;
  background: red;

}

.content {
  flex:1;
  background:green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="env">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Way more content than in all the others because this one has so much to say and doesn't know when to stop...it always does that...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Content 3
      </p>
      <p>
        Content 4
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy3Lzu75/7/

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the solution and for the flexbox example :) 
To be honest, it crossed my mind for this, too. But somehow I'm still hestitant to use it because of all those IE zombies out there.